# What does $\frac{dy}{dx}$ mean in calculus?

Tags: calculus

In calculus, does $\frac{dy}{dx}$ represents the slope of a function? If so, what does $d$ in the numerator represents in $\frac{d}{dx}$? And why does $\frac{d}{dx} y=\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: The notation comes from Liebniz, I believe, who thought in terms of "infinitesimally small change in y" in proportion to "infinitesimally small change in x".  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_notation

Comment: It is a single symbol, and _not_ a fraction. It just behaves like one some times. Specifically, it doesn't have a numerator, and there is no $d$. There is only $\frac d{dx}$.

Comment: @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman: Leibniz, not Liebniz.

Comment: I know, but it's too late to fix typos.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551124/notation-for-higher-degree-derivatives/2000010#2000010

Answer (score 0):

The notation comes from Leibniz, back in that day they dealt primarily with infinitesimal numbers, such as $\epsilon$. Back then it wasn't rigorously defined as it didn't happen until the 19th and 20th century that mathematics got a rigorous foundation.

His idea was that if $y=f(x)$ then the derivative is the infinitesimal change in $y$ value divided by the infinitesimal change in $x$ value. This can be put into a proper fraction and used as a normal fraction with all the rules still apply. In the 60s I think it was the concept of infinitesimal was rigorously defined and now can be shown to be true and rigorous.

From this the notation follows quite naturally and all the identities we use.

Comment: What do you mean by "such as $\epsilon$"? What's $\epsilon$?

Comment: In modern mathematics and hyperreals, $\epsilon$ is usually denoted for an infinitesimal and $\omega$ is commonly a transfinite number there.